# How do I select all anchors with a specific href?

Tags: jquery, html

I've got the following code to track pageviews for external links matching a particular URL.

```
    $("a").each(function(i){
        if (
            $(this).attr('href') == "http://example.com/external/link/" || 
            $(this).attr('href') == "http://example.com/external/link"
        ) {
            $(this).click(function(){
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/external/pagename']);
            });
        }
    });
```

This code works, but it's extremely inefficient for pages with a lot of links.  Is there a way to use a selector to select all the anchors with matching hrefs instead of scanning through all the links on the page?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use the [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('a[href^="http://example.com/external/link"]').click(function() {
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/external/pagename']);
});
```

Comment: This is how it's done! You can use this in conjuction with my [Google Analytics plugin](http://writeless.se/2011/01/a-no-fuzz-asynchronous-google-analytics-plugin/)

Comment: use `a[href$="pattern"]` to match end of string.

Answer (score 12):

Yes

```
$('a[href^="http://example.com/external/link"]').click(function() {});
```

Using the attribute selector you can look for a particular `href`. Instead of the normal `href=` you might expect, I have used `href^=` which matches any element which *starts with* the specified string.

Also you do not need to use `each` to bind to the click event of all the anchor tags you will select. `click()` will automatically do this for you.

```
$("a[href^="http://example.com/external/link"]").click(function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/external/pagename']);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery getting all hrefs would be like:

```
var href = 'http://www.google.com';
var elements = $('a[href=' + href + ']');

alert("Found: " + elements.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use attribute ends with selector as well if you need to get elements with some specific ending attribute. Something like this:

```
$('a[href$=your text]') == "your text"
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Another Simple way is:

```
$('a[href="MY_ANCHOR_TEXT_HERE"]');
```

Gives the list of all the anchor tags in the current page.
To get the anchor tags in a div ID you can use:

```
$('#MY_DIV_ID a[href="MY_ANCHOR_TEXT_HERE"]')
```

To get the size use:

```
$('#MY_DIV_ID a[href="MY_ANCHOR_TEXT_HERE"]').size()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href^="http://example.com/external/link"]').click( function(e){
  // you do want to track which link was clicked, yes?
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', $(this).attr('href') ]);
  // suppress default click or you'll leave the page immediately:
  e.preventDefault(); 
  do_other_stuff_presumably_with_gaq();
});
```

Comment: The attr('href') of the link is known, I simply want to track whether it was clicked. I don't understand why preventDefault() is used.  The link should still clickthrough to the external URL.

Comment: You're adding the link info to the _gaq array, but then doing what? If you're immediately taken to the link destination, _gaq[] will be lost, unless perhaps you're opening the link in a new window.

Comment: the .push function doesn't work like a typical array's push() function -- the items pushed are executed immediately.  See http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApi_gaq.html#_gaq.push for more info

Comment: @Jazzerus, thanks for the clarification; I don't use `_gaq`, so now I know. I guess we can leave for another day the debate over whether it's a good idea to override `push`. I understand why Google's doing it that way, but it has a bit of a bad smell about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can the code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("href") == "http://example.com/external/link/")
    {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
});
 </script>
```

```
  <a href="http://example.com/external/link/">a website link</a>
```

Comment: While this does work, I would recommend not doing it this way as it has to loop through every anchor on the website. Which could be hundreds or more.