# How to select anchor tag href value in external link jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

This is my code to create an external link(http:www.vv.com) for the selected text. Again select another text and create an external link (http:www.aa.com) for that text.

1. Now am select the both External link. Only show the first External link ('href'= http://www.vv.com)   href value.
2. Now am select the one External link. Only show that External link  href value.

   ```
   <body> 
   <h1>Create a link</h1> 
   Select some text and click the button. The selected text will become the named hyperlink<br>
   My Homepage<br>
   My Favorite<br>
   My Search Page<br><br>
   <button onclick="createLink(event)">Make it a link</button> 
   <script>
   function createLink(e){//b.b. Troy III p.a.e.
    if(e.target){ //get ATL
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var selects = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("a");
        alert(selects);

       var b = range.toString();  
       alert(b);
       var z = document.createElement("a");
       var l2 = prompt("Enter URL:", "http://");
       if (l2 == null) return;
           b = b.link(l2);
           z.innerHTML=b;
           range.deleteContents();
           range.insertNode(z)
           }
    else{ //get the ATW
           document.execCommand("CreateLink") 
   }
   }
   </script>
   </body>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href^="http://example.com/external/link"]').click(function() {
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/external/pagename']);
});
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629863/how-do-i-select-all-anchors-with-a-specific-href)