# Check if anchor has specific url with jQuery no duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery

Heyo,

I'm currently trying to create a script that checks `if` one of the `anchor-elements` has a specific `url`. I've tryed this but it didn't work out for me at all. What am I missing?

```js
var url =  '/right_url';

if ($('a').attr('href') == url ) {
  $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="test" href="/right_url">Test 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I was trying to find a different solution for my problem because the [attribute = value] didn't work in my case. In the post you recommended as a duplicate the solution is a different one than in this post. Why would you even mark a question as a duplicate if there hasn't been an answer yet. Just wait 15mins and you would have seen that by yourself -.-

Comment: The attribute method works fine in your case, as you can see in [@Nikhil's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53204559/519413). You must have been doing something wrong or the example in your question does not accurately reflect your HTML.

Comment: How about i dont want to use [attribute = value] and i was looking for a different solution? Just useless to mark a question as a duplicate if it clearly isnt.

Comment: Do you mean like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43318182/519413) in the duplicate? Remember to research yourself first. It's an important skill for a developer to learn.

Comment: Learn by searching or learn by asking ... were is the difference lol

Comment: @Rory McCrossan And im not going thou every single question on Stackoverflow ... why does this website allow users to upvote and mark an answere. Were is your problem with having 2 questions that might ask the same but have different solutions ... i seriously don't get you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer the specific element with `this` you have to loop through all the element so that you can check the attribute:

```js
var url =  '/right_url';
$('a').each(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('href') == url ) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="test" href="/right_url">Test 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Though I think you do not need to use loop and  use `this` to achieve what you want. You can simply use *href* attribute in the selector to add the *class*:

```js
var url =  '/right_url';
$(`a[href='${url}'`).addClass('active');
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="test" href="/right_url">Test 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```js
var url =  'right_url';
$('a[href='+url+']').addClass('active');
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="test" href="right_url">Test 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```